# Unable to set the permission of a file dynamically in Python

Tags: python

Following are two scenarios:

```
os.chmod(filename,0755)
```

and

```
permissionBits=oct(path_info.st_mode)[-4:]
os.chmod(filename,permissionBits)
```

Scenario 1 works perfectly fine while in 2nd scenario system throws an exception.
When I print the value of "permissionBits" it prints the required value. (e.g. 0755 )

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What's the exception? And are you sure that `permissionBits` is the right type? Make sure you print with `repr(permissionBits)`.

Comment: Hey Thank you.. I was little careless. I was not printing Exception. Exception says "an Integer is required" . I type-casted the variable to int  and it works now

Comment: But when I type cast 0755 becomes 755 and what I need is 0755

Comment: It looks like [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod) actually have a set of constants you'd be better off using instead (assuming they cover all the necessary conditions), you could set them up in a dictionary to convert from the string to the relevant constant.

Answer (score 2):

The first passes the permissions as a number. The second passes a *string* containing the octal representation of the permissions.

`path_info.st_mode` is likely already a number:

```
os.chmod(filename, path_info.st_mode)
```

Comment: Hey Thank you. I needed to convert the number (path_info.st_mode) into octal to set the permissions.

Comment: Basically I want the code to perform the operation "os.chmod(filename,0755)" where 0755 can vary depending upon the input file

Comment: A number is a number. The radix used for its representation doesn't matter.